# Have trouble using NCBI c++ toolkit

Tags: c++, qt, dll, blast, ncbi

I'm trying implement a small program to do blast and obtain result without browsers.
The ncbi c++ toolkit seems like what I'm looking for, however, I met some problem of using it.

My environment is windows with MSVC 2010 c++ compiler and QT framework,
I've download, configure, and build the toolkit according to the following instruction.

http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK7167/

and I have all libs  (.*lib files) at the directory below:

**ncbi_cxx--12_0_0\compilers\msvc1000_prj\dll\lib\ReleaseDLL**

Following is an example provided by ncbi, I'm trying to do similar stuff.
http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/IEB/ToolBox/CPP_DOC/lxr/source/src/sample/app/blast/remote_blast_demo.cpp

After everything seems ready, I create a project (with Qt Creator) and try to use the toolkit.
However, the problem occurs when I include any of the header files, for example

```
#include <corelib/ncbiapp.hpp>
```

I have no clue how to solve the compiler error when including ncbi libraries.The error message is as follows:

> 'ncbi::CUtf8::AsUTF8' redefinition of
>   default parameter : parameter 2    (ncbistr.hpp line 2861)
>
> 'ncbi::CStringUTF8 ncbi::CUtf8::AsUTF8(const ncbi::TCharUCS2*,ncbi::SIZE_TYPE)' : member function already defined or declared     (ncbistr.hpp line 2861)
>
> 'ncbi::CUtf8::AsUTF8' : missing default parameter for parameter 2 (ncbistr.hpp line 2861)

I spent days on figuring how to use this toolkit, if anyone can give me some idea, I'll really appreciate.

By the way, in the project file I do include path and libs.

```
INCLUDEPATH += "../../lib/ncbi_cxx--12_0_0/include"
LIBS += "../../lib/ncbi_cxx--12_0_0/compilers/msvc1000_prj/dll/lib/ReleaseDLL/*.lib"
```

Comment: did you succceed? Please try more recent version of ncbi toolkit.